# junitparameter exception method should have no parameter

Tags: java, exception, junitparams

By using JUnitParameter for testing a methode I have an exception. My code is similar to lot of example on JUnitParameter:

```
    private Object parametersForTestSetDistanceFormated() {
    return new Object[][]{    
        {100,   "_1,__ km"}, 
        {100,   "1_,__ km"}, 
        {1100,  "11,__ km"}, 
        {110,   "1_,1_ km"}, 
        {111,   "1_,11 km"}};
}
/**
 * Test of setDistanceFormated method, of class ClientFormated.
 */
@Test
@Parameters
public void testSetDistanceFormated(final int exptDist, final String  distFormated) {
    System.out.println("setDistanceFormated");
    ClientFormated instance = new ClientFormated();             

    instance.setDistanceFormated(distFormated);
    assertEquals(exptDist, (long) instance.getDistance());
}
```

and then I obtain the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Exception: Method testSetDistanceFormated should have no parameters
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.verifyMethodCanBeRunByStandardRunner(JUnitParamsRunner.java:429)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:420)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:386)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Method testSetDistanceFormated should have no parameters
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:76)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.verifyMethodCanBeRunByStandardRunner(JUnitParamsRunner.java:427)
    ... 20 more
```

I haven't found related on the web...

My whole classe:

```
import com.entities.Client;
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ClientFormatedTest {

private Object parametersForTestSetDistanceFormated() {
    return new Object[][]{    
        {100,   "_1,__ km"}, 
        {100,   "1_,__ km"}, 
        {1100,  "11,__ km"}, 
        {110,   "1_,1_ km"}, 
        {111,   "1_,11 km"}};
}

/**
 * Test of setDistanceFormated method, of class ClientFormated.
 */
@Test
@Parameters
public void testSetDistanceFormated(final int exptDist, final String  distFormated) {
    System.out.println("setDistanceFormated");
    ClientFormated instance = new ClientFormated();             

    instance.setDistanceFormated(distFormated);
    assertEquals(exptDist, (long) instance.getDistance());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct `@Parameters` annotation?

Comment: Paste the whole class, together with imports. Do you have the `@RunWith(JUniParamsRunner.class)` annotation?

Comment: Yes as you can see I have the @RunWith(JUniParamsRunner.class)

Comment: I have found. I have mix imports from JUnit and from JUnitParams. By using correct imports it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imports need to be updated like :

```
import com.entities.Client;
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
```

Now it works

Answer (score 20):

Add @RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class) annotation above class
as

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class TestClass {
```

Also you need to import

```
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using wrong import for `@Parameters` - it should be `junitparams.Parameters`, not `org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters`

Comment: Yes I found at the time than you. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

**This error may show up when your test method(having @Test annotation) have any arguments**

For anyone else who came here because of the same error they are seeing but not with JUitParameter.

I hit this same error, in my code.

```
java.lang.Exception: Method assertResult() should be public


at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoid(FrameworkMethod.java:96)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:74)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:155)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateTestMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:208)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:188)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

The error was because for a method with argument, I had accidentally added a @Test tag. (Added it when I was testing just that method and then forgot to remove it). Silly me.
Worked fine when I removed the @Test.
**If you want the @Test, then the method shouldn't have any arguments**

```
@Test
void assertResult(String result) {
    Assert.assertTrue(!"403".equals(result) && !"404".equals(result) && !"400".equals(result));
    Assert.assertNotNull(result);
}
```

Comment: "If you want the @Test, then the method shouldn't have any arguments" this is the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across this article while looking for an issue to a similar problem.  I was getting an exception like this:

> java.lang.Exception: Method x should have no parameters

It turns out I was using the wrong import for the `@Test` annotation.
I originally used `import org.junit.Test;`
but what I needed to use was `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

Long story short, make sure you are checking your imports, sometimes the auto-generated ones aren't really what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JMockit, then adding below snippet resolves the issue

```
import mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit;

@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class TestClass
```